# Using GDAL, NetCDF4 to GeoTIFF wrongly rotates the output GeoTIFF file 90 degrees

Tags: raster, gdal, netcdf, rioxarray

I have written a code that transforms a NetCDF4 data (it can be downloaded from [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1W3W3p0P32kMvOIfQB4kLSDptjQUSyR6-/view?usp=sharing)) to GeoTIFF file using [this](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/convert-netcdf4-file-geotiff-using-python-chonghua-yin/) link. This code works fine. But it seems that it rotates my data 90 or -90 degrees:

```
import sys
import numpy as np
from osgeo import gdal, osr, gdal_array
import xarray as xr

filepath = '/home/gpm/3B-DAY.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20170216-S000000-E235959.V06.nc4'
var_name = 'precipitationCal'
src_ds = gdal.Open(filepath)
if src_ds is None:
    print('Open failed')
    sys.exit()


# if len(src_ds.GetSubDatasets()) > 1:
# if there is more than one variable in the netCDF4
subdataset = 'NETCDF:"' + filepath + '":' + var_name
print('subdataset:', subdataset)
src_ds_sd = gdal.Open(subdataset)

print('opening dataset successful', src_ds_sd)

# getting info of the variable‌ (subdataset)
ndv = src_ds_sd.GetRasterBand(1).GetNoDataValue()

xsize = src_ds_sd.RasterXSize
ysize = src_ds_sd.RasterYSize

geo_t = src_ds_sd.GetGeoTransform()
# geo_t = (geo_t[3], geo_t[5], geo_t[4], geo_t[0], geo_t[2], geo_t[1])
projection = osr.SpatialReference()
projection.ImportFromWkt(src_ds_sd.GetProjectionRef())

# close the subdataset and the whole dataset
# src_ds_sd = None
# src_ds = None

# read data using xrray
xr_ensemble = xr.open_dataset(filepath)
array = xr_ensemble[var_name]
array = np.ma.masked_array(array, mask=array==ndv, fill_value=ndv)
# array = np.transpose(array, (0, 2, 1))

final = (ndv, xsize, ysize, geo_t, projection, array)

datatype = gdal_array.NumericTypeCodeToGDALTypeCode(array.dtype)

if type(datatype) != np.int:
    if datatype.startswith('gdal.GDT_')==False:
        datatype = eval('gdal.GDT_' + datatype)

new_file_name = var_name +'33'+ '.tif'
zsize = array.shape[0]

# create a driver
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
# set nans to the original no data value
array[np.isnan(array)] = ndv
# setup the dataset with zsize bands
dataset = driver.Create(new_file_name, xsize, ysize, zsize, datatype)
dataset.SetGeoTransform(geo_t)

spatial_reference = osr.SpatialReference()
spatial_reference.ImportFromEPSG(4326)

dataset.SetProjection(spatial_reference.ExportToWkt())
#%%
# write each slice of the array along the zsize
for i in range(zsize):
    dataset.GetRasterBand(i+1).WriteArray(array[i])
    dataset.GetRasterBand(i+1).SetNoDataValue(ndv)

dataset.FlushCache()
```

I am sure that I should change `geo_t` in some way. Currently the shape of the `array` is: (1, 3600, 1800)

3600 values for `lon`, 1800 values for `lat`

Here is the output geotiff file in QGIS:
[image]. This is the output geotiff file's properties in QGIS:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this, I would recommend [rioxarray](https://github.com/corteva/rioxarray):

For some reason, GDAL seems to interpret x as y and y as x. If you open it up:

```py
import xarray
import rioxarray

rds = rioxarray.open_rasterio(
    "3B-DAY.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20170216-S000000-E235959.V06.nc4",
    variable="precipitationCal",
)
```

You can see that y is way out of bounds with values close to 180 and -180.
[image]

So, I would recommend just opening with xarray:

```py
xds = xarray.open_dataset(
    "3B-DAY.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20170216-S000000-E235959.V06.nc4",
)
```

then, some tweaks to get things in the right location and metadata setup:

```py
precip = xds.precipitationCal.transpose('time', 'lat', 'lon')
precip.rio.set_spatial_dims(x_dim="lon", y_dim="lat", inplace=True)
precip.rio.write_crs("EPSG:4326", inplace=True)
```

And finally, write to a raster:

```py
precip.rio.to_raster(new_file_name)
```

[image]

Comment: This works. Thank you

Comment: A few days back, I wrote a class to do this. Can I post the entire class here as an answer?

Comment: your mentioning to use xarray and rioxarray packages was GREATLY helpful. These two packages seem to have lots of capabilities that I need. Thank you very much.

Comment: Glad to hear that it is helpful to you 

Comment: @snowman2, I tried your solution but my terminal shows this error `NotGeoreferencedWarning: The given matrix is equal to Affine.identity or its flipped counterpart. GDAL may ignore this matrix and save no geotransform without raising an error. This behavior is somewhat driver-specific. s = writer(path, mode, driver=driver,`
can you please help?

Comment: Sure - if you open a new question, add code you've tried, add input files, and link it here, I can take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the class I wrote that is able to extract the data from the NetCDF4 file and save it as a new GeoTiff file. I compared my result with @snowman2 ' s and they were the same:

```
from osgeo import gdal, osr, gdal_array
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np

########################################################################
# below classes are used to handle output netcdf files from queires and save them into local machine
########################################################################

# class that is used to convert output netcdf files into geotiff files
class NetcdfHandler(object):
    def __init__(self, filepath, var_name):
        self.__filepath = filepath
        self.__begin_date = ''
        self.__var_name = var_name

    # def create_required_outputs(self, newRasterfn, rasterOrigin, pixelWidth, pixelHeight, array):
    def create_geotiff(self, new_raster_dir):

        result = self.get_variable_info()
        if result:
            print('result is successful, ')

            ndv, rows, cols, geo_t, out_raster_srs, data = result
            # data = data[::-1]

            # print('rows:', rows)
            # print('cols:', cols)


            raster_origin = (geo_t[0], geo_t[3])

            pixel_width = geo_t[1]
            pixel_height = geo_t[5]

            # the below line was not necessary for the GPM, however, it was used in the gdal website from which
            # I got assistance to write this code
            # reversed_arr = data[::-1]  # reverse array so the tif looks like the array
            return self.array2raster(new_raster_dir, raster_origin, pixel_width, pixel_height, data)  # converts array to raster

        return 'unsuccessful!'
    # get some variables that are used in create_geotiff method
    def get_variable_info(self):
        # print('directory:', self.__filepath)

        src_ds = gdal.Open(self.__filepath)


        if src_ds is None:
            print('Open failed')
            return None


        if len(src_ds.GetSubDatasets()) > 1:
            # if there is more than one variable in the netCDF4
            subdataset = 'NETCDF:"' + self.__filepath + '":' + self.__var_name

            src_ds_sd = gdal.Open(subdataset)


            print('opening dataset successful', src_ds_sd)

            # getting info of the variable‌ (subdataset)
            ndv = src_ds_sd.GetRasterBand(1).GetNoDataValue()

            cols = src_ds_sd.RasterXSize
            rows = src_ds_sd.RasterYSize

            geo_t = src_ds_sd.GetGeoTransform()

            # just for the GPM products we have to change n_rows and n_cols together,
            # otherwise it should be removed so that it can automatically detects the geo_t
            # as there was a difficulty with this data, I decided to change this manually
            geo_t = (-360+geo_t[3], -geo_t[5], geo_t[4], geo_t[0], geo_t[2], geo_t[1])

            # this option also should be checked
            # geo_t = (-geo_t[3], -geo_t[5], geo_t[4], geo_t[0], geo_t[2], geo_t[1])

            # print('geo_t', geo_t)
            out_raster_srs = osr.SpatialReference()
            out_raster_srs.ImportFromEPSG(4326)

            # print('projection ref', src_ds_sd.GetProjectionRef())

            # close the subdataset and the whole dataset

            src_ds_sd = None
            src_ds = None

            # read data using xrray
            # TODO: use src_ds_sd to get the dataset without using xr_ensemble again
            xr_ensemble = xr.open_dataset(self.__filepath)

            self.__begin_date = xr_ensemble.BeginDate

            data = xr_ensemble[self.__var_name]
            data = np.ma.masked_array(data, mask=data==ndv, fill_value=ndv)


            # for gpm we have to change 2nd and 3rd axis because when we want to save the array,
            # it will rotate -90 degrees otherwise
            data = np.array(np.transpose(data, (0, 2, 1))[0])
            cols, rows = rows, cols

            return ndv, rows, cols, geo_t, out_raster_srs, data

    def array2raster(self, new_raster_dir, raster_origin, pixel_width, pixel_height, array):

        cols = array.shape[1]
        rows = array.shape[0]
        origin_x = raster_origin[0]
        origin_y = raster_origin[1]

        driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')

        output_path = ''.join([new_raster_dir, self.__var_name, '-', self.__begin_date, '.tif'])

        out_raster = driver.Create(output_path, cols, rows, 1, gdal.GDT_Float32)
        out_raster.SetGeoTransform((origin_x, pixel_width, 0, origin_y, 0, pixel_height))
        outband = out_raster.GetRasterBand(1)
        outband.WriteArray(array)
        out_raster_srs = osr.SpatialReference()
        out_raster_srs.ImportFromEPSG(4326)
        out_raster.SetProjection(out_raster_srs.ExportToWkt())
        outband.FlushCache()

        return 'successful!'

    def create_time(self):
        date_string = None


    @property
    def filepath(self):
        return self.__filepath
    @filepath.setter
    def filepath(self, value):
        self.__filepath = value




#######################################
# test the class ######################
#######################################

path = '3B-DAY.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20170216-S000000-E235959.V06.nc4'

handler = NetcdfHandler(path, 'precipitationCal')
result = handler.create_geotiff('')
print('handler status:%s' % result)
```