# xarray NetCDF with groups to GeoTIFF

Tags: python, raster, netcdf, rioxarray, xarray

I am trying to convert NetCDF files, available from this [link,](https://zenodo.org/record/5956612) to raster or geotiff files using Python 3. After reading the a NetCDF file using the package netcdf4, it appears to have groups: CO2, CO2_uncertainty, and O2.

```
import netCDF4 as nc
xds = nc.Dataset('GCP_Global_1959.nc')
xds
```

I then tried to open the file with xarray and had the following output where I can see the coordinates and time slices. Although, the coordinates seem to be out of bounds.

```
import xarray as xr
xds = xr.open_dataset('GCP_Global_1959.nc')
```

[image]

Finally, I tried to add a group to the open_dataset call but coordinates are missing.

```
xds = xr.open_dataset('GCP_Global_1959.nc', group='CO2')
```

[image]

I've tried the solution from [Using GDAL, NetCDF4 to GeoTIFF wrongly rotates the output GeoTIFF file 90 degrees](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/366939) but it doesn't seem to work.

How can I convert this NetCDF file to a raster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close already! :)

```
import rioxarray
import rasterio
import xarray as xr

# Open the coordinates as a xr.Dataset.
ds_coords = xr.open_dataset('GCP_Global_1959.nc')

# Open the data inside the group as a xr.Dataset.
ds = xr.open_dataset('GCP_Global_1959.nc', group='CO2')

# Add the coordinates to the "data"-dataset.
ds = ds.assign_coords(ds_coords.coords)

# Assign a CRS.
ds = ds.rio.write_crs(4326)

# Rename some dimensions.
ds = ds.rename({"lat": "y", "lon": "x"})

# Create 1 geoTIFF per variable.
for var in ds.data_vars:
  ds[var].rio.to_raster(f"{var}.tif")
```

Check if it works:

```
test_ds = xr.open_dataset("OIL.tif", engine = "rasterio")
print(test_ds)

<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:      (band: 12, x: 3600, y: 1800)
Coordinates:
  * band         (band) int64 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
  * x            (x) float64 -179.9 -179.8 -179.7 -179.6 ... 179.7 179.8 179.9
  * y            (y) float64 -89.95 -89.85 -89.75 -89.65 ... 89.75 89.85 89.95
    spatial_ref  int64 ...
Data variables:
    band_data    (band, y, x) float32 ...
```